# how to copy files with subfolders

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, cp

I have folder with subfolders and files inside. I want to copy all html files from all subfolders in main folder (parent) and have it in new folder (dist) with the same folder structure. (I am using Mac)

```
parent

subfolder1 - file1.html, file4.html
subfolder2 - file2.html
subfolder3 - file3.html
```

Expected result is dist folder with structure the same as in parent folder:

```
dist 

subfolder1 - file1.html, file4.html
subfolder2 - file2.html
subfolder3 - file3.html
```

I am using this command:

```
cp -R ./parent/templates/**/*.html ./dist/templates
```

But the result is templates folder filled up with .html files but no subfolders copied.

```
dist
file1.html
file2.html
file3.html
file4.html
```

So I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> how to do it.

With GNU `cp` you could try:

```
cd ./parent/templates/ &&
cp -R --parents **/*.html ../../dist/templates
```

But I would recommend to use `rsync`.

Comment: Thanks. Finally I've chosen rsync as more simple :)